# How can I see the phones IPv6 details?

Tags: networking

My phone is connected to an IPv6 network. I'd like to know what IPv6 address is assigned my phone. Also which router the phone is using as well as any IPv6 DNS.

I'm able to see the stateless address using whatismyipv6.com but I'm not able to see the stateful address directly on the phone. I've checked the settings for the Wi-Fi but I'm only able to see the IPv4 details there.

Comment: Does my answer solves your problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this Third Party apps

[IP Address](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/ip-address/6ea8b113-72c5-44a3-ad30-14ed2e56719f) {This app provides your IP address in IPv4 and IPv6 (IPng) networks.}

[Admin Tools](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/admin-tools/5544bfd2-f2bf-44e6-98cf-b16e821396e6) {This app provides some Network Related tools including DNS.}